# Uninstall old Qt Creator, keep the new one

Tags: unity, qt, qt-creator

When I execute Qt Creator from the Unity dash (Ubuntu 16.04) I find 2 versions of Qt Creator (I installed both of them):

- Qt Creator 3.5.1 based on Qt 5.5.1
- Qt creator (community) 4.7.1 based on Qt 5.11.2

I want to remove Qt Creator 3.5.1 and if possible Qt 5.5.1 but I can't find the way to do it, nor the folder where the launcher icon is (I thought that if I find where the launcher icon is pointing I could delete that folder but maybe it's not that safe to do so?).

Comment: Did you install 3.5.1 through Ubuntu and 4.7.1 by downloading the online installer directly from the Qt website?

Comment: I'm not sure now but I think I downloaded both versions. First I downloaded the older one and after realizing it wasn't the last release I downloaded 4.7.1

Comment: You could try `sudo apt remove qtcreator` and then `sudo apt autoremove`. If the old one was installed through apt (which I think is likely), this should remove it. Let me know if that works.

Comment: @gsxruk you were right, that was the solution. Thanx